# ¿Como asignar transparencia de fondo a mi toolbar?

Tags: android

Buen dia.

En mi aplicacion tengo un toolbar en el cual hay un boton que llama al menu lateral.

[image: appbar1]

Como podria hacer para poner transparencia de fondo para que quede algo asi

[image: appbar2]

Este es el xml del toolbar

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/NavigationViewTheme">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.CustomTheme"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clickable="true" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

De atemano gracias.

Answer (score 1):

La solución fue quitar esta propiedad del contenedor de todos mis fragments

```
 app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```